# how to verify* that the minimum of the function $s(t) = -t x+t^{2} f(t c) v$ is $t=\frac{1}{c} \log \left(1+\frac{x c}{v}\right)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Is there a way (without using derivatives | thus the * in the title) to verify that whether or not the minimum of the function $s(t) = -t x+t^{2} f(t c) v$ is $t=\frac{1}{c} \log \left(1+\frac{x c}{v}\right)$ ?

where $f$ is the function defined as follows : $f(0)=1 / 2$ and for every $t \in \mathbb{R}^{*}$
by : $$ 
f(t)=\frac{\exp (t)-1-t}{t^{2}}$$ all of the other variables are constants, $v$ and $c$ in particular are both non-zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(t) := 1+c^2s(t)/v$. Then
$$
g(t)=-\frac{txc^2}{v} + \exp(tc)-tc=\exp(tc)-tc\left(1+\frac{xc}{v}\right).
$$

Thus, if * denotes [convex conjugation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate#Table_of_selected_convex_conjugates), then one recognizes
$$
\begin{split}
\inf_t g(t) &=-\sup_t tc(1+xc/v)-\exp(tc) = -(y \mapsto \exp(yc))^*|_{y=c(1+xc/v)}\\
&= c(1+xc/v)(1-\log(1+xc/v))
\end{split}
$$
which is attained at $t=(1/c)\log(1+xc/v)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you please tell me what I should review to understand the second equality $ -(y \mapsto \exp(yc))^*|_{y=c(1+xc/v)}$, everything else was clear, thanks.

Comment: For the second property, you only need to know (1) definition of convex conjugates, and (2) The transformation properties of convex conjugates (e.g, see line 3 of this table https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate#Table_of_selected_convex_conjugates). It also goes without saying that $\sup_t tc(1+xc/v)-\exp(tc) = h^*(c(1+xcv))$, where $h(y) := \exp(yc)$.

Comment: just got it, thanks, neat answer.

Answer (score 1):

Write $u=c^{-1}\log (1+xc/v)$. If you already know that $f(t)> 0$, then you can write

$$s(t) = ve^{cu}((t-u)^2f(ct-cu)-u^2 f(-cu))$$
which makes it clear that $s(t)\geq - v e^{cu}u^2 f(-cu)$, equality holding iff $t=u$.